# Variable is not incrementing correctly

Tags: c, increment

I want to add numbers (`nums`) in my `distCasas` array but `idx` is inscrementing wrong. I stay with `nums` in index

```
0, 2, 4, ...
```

not

```
0, 1, 2, ...
```

The code:

```
int numCasas, idx, distCasas[10], nums;

scanf("%d", &numCasas);

for (idx = 0; idx < numCasas; idx++)
{
    scanf("%d", &nums);

    distCasas[idx] = nums;
    idx++;
}
```

Comment: you are incrementing the idx variable two times per iteration of the for-loop. once in the loop-header itself and once at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: Did this help? If it did, it's generally seen as polite to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are incrementing idx twice. Get rid of the second idx++ so that your code looks like the following.

```
scanf("%d", &numCasas);

for (idx = 0; idx < numCasas; idx++)
{
    scanf("%d", &nums);

    distCasas[idx] = nums;
}
```

Comment: if u do this he will put numbers always in index 1 and dont add a lot of numbers in array...

Comment: @rubcpires: No, as `idx` is incremented exactly once per loop, by the expression `idx++` in the loop's head.

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing `idx` twice. Once inside the `{}` of the `for` loop and once inside the `()` of the for loop.

Remove one of them, preferably the one inside the `{}` part.

```
for (idx = 0; idx < numCasas; idx++)
{
    scanf("%d", &nums);
    distCasas[idx] = nums;
}
```